# PHP - Post Action

Tags: html, wordpress

```
<form method="post" action="/page/?foo=ABC">
    <select name="foo">
        <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
        <option value="DEF">DEF</option>
    </select>
    <select name="bar">
        <option value="GHI">GHI</option>
        <option value="JKL">JKL</option>
    </select>
    <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    <input type="submit" value="">
</form>
```

I have the above form on a Wordpress site. If I go to /page/?foo=ABC, this page shows me everything as it should where foo = ABC.

What do I need to set the action as to get the option from the select?

Comment: use `$_POST['foo']`, and not $_GET or $_REQUEST. request's contents will depend on your [variables_order](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) .ini setting.

Comment: So you want to set foo to selected option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form needs to use GET instead of POST:

```
<form method="get" action="/page/">
```

Then then all the inputs will be appended to the URL in the manner you seek.

Answer (score -1):

As Marc B said in the comments, use

```
$_POST['foo']
```